# Can't retrieve, reset or update select2 options

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

Please see this jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/L1tns1yh/1/

First, it doesn't retrieve proper `.select2('data')`

Then, clicking the button doesn't reset the options, tried different ways I've found on the internets...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the following, i dont realy like this solution but it works if you create a new select2:

```
$button.click(function () {
  $('#select').select2('destroy').empty().select2({allowClear: true,
  placeholder: 'Placeholder...'});
});
```

Comment: Thank you, just adding `.empty()` before setting 'data' was enough!

Answer (score 1):

Please update button click event like below,

```
$button.click(function () {
  $select.empty();
});
```

Comment: I'm not trying to clear selection. I'm trying to clear options

Comment: this will clear the whole select2 and Op has to identify everything again, such as placeholder. He just needs to update the data only.

Comment: do you mean that selected option will be removed only ?

Comment: Yes, that's what he wants to archive. please check @Mapendra 's answer. He's using same method as your, but required to add in `{allowClear: true,
  placeholder: 'Placeholder...'})`